# Pygame sprite assistance

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've basically just started developing with PyGame and I am having trouble with the whole Sprite concept. I have been looking every where for guides on how to use it, I just can't seem to find any. I would like to know the basic concept of how it all works. This is the code I have been working on:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

size = width, height = 320, 320
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

xDirection = 0
yDirection = 0
xPosition = 32
yPosition = 256

blockAmount = width/32

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill([0, 155, 255])
pygame.display.set_caption("Mario Test")
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())

mainCharacter = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
mainCharacter.image = pygame.image.load("data/character.png").convert()
mainCharacter.rect = mainCharacter.image.get_rect()
mainCharacter.rect.topleft = [xPosition, yPosition]
screen.blit(mainCharacter.image, mainCharacter.rect)

grass = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
grass.image = pygame.image.load("data/grass.png").convert()
grass.rect = grass.image.get_rect()
for i in range(blockAmount):
    blockX = i * 32
    blockY = 288
    grass.rect.topleft = [blockX, blockY]
    screen.blit(grass.image, grass.rect)

grass.rect.topleft = [64, 256]  
screen.blit(grass.image, grass.rect.topleft )

running = False
jumping = False 
falling = False
standing = True

jumpvel = 22
gravity = -1

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                running = True
                xRun = -5
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                running = True
                xRun = 5
            elif event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_SPACE:
                jumping = True
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_RIGHT:
                running = False


    if running == True:
        xPosition += xRun

    if mainCharacter.rect.right >= width:
        xPosition = xPosition - 10
        print "hit"
        running = False
    elif mainCharacter.rect.left <= 0:
        xPosition = xPosition + 10
        print "hit"
        running = False

    screen.fill([0, 155, 255])

    for i in range(blockAmount):
        blockX = i * 32
        blockY = 288
        grass.rect.topleft = [blockX, blockY]
        screen.blit(grass.image, grass.rect)

    grass.rect.topleft = [64, 64]   
    screen.blit(grass.image, grass.rect.topleft )


    if jumping:
        yPosition -= jumpvel
        print jumpvel
        jumpvel += gravity
        if jumpvel < -22:
            jumping = False
        if mainCharacter.rect.bottom == grass.rect.top:
            jumping = False

    if not jumping:
        jumpvel = 22


    mainCharacter.rect.topleft = [xPosition, yPosition]
    screen.blit(mainCharacter.image,mainCharacter.rect)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

basically I just want to know how to make these grass blocks into sprites in a group, so that when I add my player (also a sprite) I can determine whether or not he is in the air or not through the collision system. Can someone please explain to me how I would do this. All I am looking for is basically a kick starter because some of the documentation is quite bad in my opinion as it doesn't completely tell you how to use it. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Pygame, sprites are very minimal. They consist of two main parts: an image and a rect. The image is what is displayed on the screen and the rect is used for positioning and collision detection. Here's an example of how your grass image could be made into a Sprite:

```
grass = pygame.image.load("grass.png")
grass = grass.convert_alpha()
grassSprite = new pygame.sprite.Sprite()
grassSprite.image = grass
#This automatically sets the rect to be the same size as your image.
grassSprite.rect = grass.get_rect()
```

Sprites are pretty pointless on their own, since you can always keep track of images and positions yourself. The advantage is in using groups. Here's an example of how a group might be used:

```
myGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
myGroup.add([sprite1,sprite2,sprite3])
myGroup.update()
myGroup.draw()
if myGroup.has(sprite2):
    myGroup.remove(sprite2)
```

This code creates a group, adds three sprites to the group, updates the sprites, draws them, checks to see if sprite2 is in the group, then removes the sprite. It is mostly straight forward, but there are some things to note:
1) Group.add() can take either a single sprite or any iterable collection of sprites, such as a list or a tuple.
2) Group.update() calls the update methods of all the Sprites it contains. Pygame's Sprite doesn't do anything when its update method is called; however, if you make a subclass of Sprite, you can override the update method to make it do something.
3) Group.draw() blits the images of all the Group's Sprites to the screen at the x and y positions of their rects. If you want to move a sprite, you change its rect's x and y positions like so: `mySprite.rect.x = 4` or `mySprite.rect.y -= 7`

One way to use Groups is to create a different group for each level. Then call the update and draw method of whichever group represents the current level. Since nothing will happen or be displayed unless those methods are called, all other levels will remain "paused" until you switch back to them. Here's an example:

```
levels = [pygame.sprite.Group(),pygame.sprite.Group(),pygame.sprite.Group()]
levels[0].add(listOfLevel0Sprites)
levels[1].add(listOfLevel1Sprites)
levels[2].add(listOfLevel2Sprites)
currentLevel = 0
while(True):
    levels[currentLevel].update()
    levels[currentLevel].draw()
```

I know this question is somewhat old, but I hope you still find it helpful!

Comment: groups are for group collision detection, not for level management.

Comment: True, they can be used for collision detection, though I believe they use a simple algorithm to check every sprite against every other sprite. Still, they provide control over updating and drawing, as well as collisions- I was just trying to give an example of the broad scope of applications for which they can be applied. True, you may want more control over level management, but then you might also want more control over collision detection.